# Can we javaagent jar file added as dependency in pom.xml rather than giving as javaagent:jarpath

Tags: java, spring, pom.xml, byte-buddy

I am developing a Java agent and want to know if there is any way calling application can use this agent jar in the application as a jar dependency in pox.xml rather than running the application with javaagent:jarpath.
Teams want to solution to be added a dependency.

I don't see any option for a calling program to  indicate the agent jar.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

What you can do is add byte-buddy-agent and attach the agent dynamically, but this still requires to invoke some init method of a class you ship.

Comment: Thank you.  Really applicate it.